# How do you serve a website from GCP app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-appengine-node

I have set up a Node.js server in Google Cloud Platform App Engine, and have also configured a custom domain, which is correctly configured and has a SSL cert.

However, I can't figure out how to actually serve through the domain.

Comment: can you add detail on what you have done, what don't work and with which error.

Comment: I understand that you followed [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/mapping-custom-domains) to configure the custom domain and [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl) to set the SSL certificate. Nonethelss, I don't really understand what exactly you are using as a server. Are you using the [built-in HTTP module](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_http.asp) to listen and serve requests? You basically just need to create the logic to listen and serve requests.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have explained what I have done. The server is set up and everything works fine. There are no errors. I simply can't find documentation on how to deploy it.

Comment: @DanielOcando Yes exactly. I have written my own (very simple) server in JavaScript. It does use the http module. It works--but only on the web preview. I want it to deploy. So it serves through my domain.

Comment: So, you have the custom domain configured as per @DanielOcando suggestion and your concern is: "How do I deploy a GAE app to a Custom domain"? Getting a better understanding of your issue will allow us to better help you. Cheers :)

Comment: @maniSidhu98 Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the GCP terminal, run this command:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

Since the server is already set up and working and the domain is already configured, that command is all that's needed to deploy.